# PySpark - Class Not Found Exception: org.tensorframes.ShapeDescription

Tags: python, tensorflow, pyspark

I am getting the following exception while running Deep Learning Pipeline in Spark.
Versions of

tensorflow and tensorframes : 2.0.0
conda : 4.8.3
pip : 20.0.2
python: 3.6

The exception comes while calling fit method of the pipeline:

```
p = Pipeline(stages=[featurizer, lr])
p_model = p.fit(train_df)
```

**Stack Trace**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/ml/base.py", line 132, in fit
    return self._fit(dataset)
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py", line 107, in _fit
    dataset = stage.transform(dataset)
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/ml/base.py", line 173, in transform
    return self._transform(dataset)
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py", line 312, in _transform
    return DataFrame(self._java_obj.transform(dataset._jdf), dataset.sql_ctx)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o56.transform.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/tensorframes/ShapeDescription
        at com.databricks.sparkdl.DeepImageFeaturizer.transform(DeepImageFeaturizer.scala:124)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.tensorframes.ShapeDescription
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
        ... 12 more
```

Any suggestions to solve this?

**Conda Environment:**
 Name                    Version
_libgcc_mutex             0.1
_tflow_select             2.3.0
absl-py                   0.9.0
argcomplete               1.11.1
asgiref                   3.2.7
asn1crypto                1.3.0
astor                     0.8.0
astroid                   2.3.3
bcrypt                    3.1.7
blas                      1.0
blinker                   1.4
c-ares                    1.15.0
ca-certificates           2020.1.1
cachetools                4.1.0
certifi                   2020.4.5.1
cffi                      1.14.0
chardet                   3.0.4
click                     7.1.1
cloudpickle               1.3.0
coverage                  5.0
cryptography              2.8
django                    3.0.5
gast                      0.2.2
google-auth               1.13.1
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.1
google-pasta              0.2.0
grpcio                    1.27.2
h5py                      2.10.0
hdf5                      1.10.4
idna                      2.9
image                     1.5.28
isort                     4.3.21
keras                     2.3.1
keras-applications        1.0.8
keras-base                2.3.1
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.3
ld_impl_linux-64          2.33.1
libedit                   3.1.20181209 
libffi                    3.2.1
libgcc-ng                 9.1.0
libgfortran-ng            7.3.0
libopenblas               0.3.6
libprotobuf               3.11.4
libsodium                 1.0.16
libstdcxx-ng              9.1.0
markdown                  3.1.1
mccabe                    0.6.1
ncurses                   6.2
nomkl                     3.0
nose                      1.3.7
numpy                     1.18.2
numpy-base                1.18.1
oauthlib                  3.1.0
openssl                   1.1.1f
opt_einsum                3.1.0
pandas                    1.0.3
parameterized             0.7.0
paramiko                  2.7.1
pillow                    7.1.1
pip                       20.0.2
protobuf                  3.11.4
pyasn1                    0.4.8
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8
pycparser                 2.20
pyjwt                     1.7.1
pylint                    2.4.4
pynacl                    1.3.0
pyopenssl                 19.1.0
pysocks                   1.7.1
python                    3.6.10
python-dateutil           2.8.1
pytz                      2019.3
pyyaml                    5.3.1
readline                  8.0
requests                  2.23.0
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0
rsa                       4.0
scipy                     1.4.1
setuptools                46.1.3
six                       1.14.0
sqlite                    3.31.1
sqlparse                  0.3.1
tensorboard               2.0.2
tensorflow                2.0.0
tensorflow-estimator      2.0.1
tensorframes              0.2.9
termcolor                 1.1.0
tk                        8.6.8
typed-ast                 1.4.1
urllib3                   1.25.8
werkzeug                  1.0.0
wheel                     0.34.2
wrapt                     1.12.1
xz                        5.2.4
yaml                      0.1.7
zlib                      1.2.11

Comment: Can you share the contents of the environment using something like `conda list` ?

Comment: Updated in the question.